# Ошибка в коде по написанию дискорд бота

Tags: бот, discord.py

Код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "", line 21, in mute
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'metion'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'metion'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса